# Main.storyboard is pitch black

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I've been coding in Xcode for a long time but I've never used the storyboard. When I opened it up  I got this pitch-black.

Does any one know how to fix this ?

[image: does any one know how to fix this]

Answer (score 1):

A lot can cause a black screen. I think, most likely, you are currently previewing dark mode. You can switch back to light mode by clicking <kbd>View as</kbd> and changing the appearance.

[image]

Or, the background color of the view might be set to black (probably not the case though). You can change this in the attributes inspector.

| Black color | System background color |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

*System Background Color is white in light mode, and black in dark mode.*

And there's always the possibility that Xcode is glitching. In that case, quit and relaunch.

Comment: I dont get the background color thing

Comment: @clusion the `System Background Color`? In iOS 13, Apple added some colors that are reactive based on whether the device is in dark or light mode. `System Background Color` is one such color.

Comment: i dont see the background option at all is what I was saying

Comment: @clusion I recorded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0O4HB1JXh8&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a datepicker set to inline mode, and it messed things up. I'd try and recall if you did anything that Xcode didn't like before it went black, and try and reverse that.